# Seaborn lineplot, TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am getting the following error when trying to plot a lineplot with seaborn.

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Minimal example reproducing error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

dataset = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "y": [1.0, 2.3, 4.5, 1.2, 3.4, 5.3, 1.1, 2.4, 3.6, 1.1, 3.3, 5.3],
    "id": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
    "seed": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
print(df.dtypes)

g = sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="id", errorbar="sd")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I have tried checking the datatypes of all inputs and Dataframe columns, and changing "id" to be an integer type (even though that is not my goal) and the error persists.

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3192

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numpy 1.24.0 [has a bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22826) that causes [an exception](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3192) within several seaborn functions. The bug has been fixed and numpy has released a new version to address it. The solution is to install numpy 1.24.1 the same way that you installed numpy 1.24.0.

Answer (score -1):

aparently there is a version issue going on
[fix](https://medium.com/@fengliplatform/seaborn-typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-input-types-dc93270a04a3)

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please provide summary/steps from link to solve the problem.